# Is it safe to store user login details in XML files outside document root

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a section of my website that requires users to register and login, and their login details are stored in separate XML files in a folder outside the public document root. So the public PHP files are in "home/public" and I'm storing the XML files in "home/private".

I've encrypted the passwords with bcrypt.

And in the "home/private" folder I've created an ".htaccess" file containing: `Deny from all`

Is this secure or is there something different I need to do to protect these files?

Comment: Why not use SQL?

Comment: PHP has a perfectly fine password API - use it. Passwords should be hashed not encrypted.

Comment: Storing user information in files on disk is going to be more-or-less exactly as secure as storing it in a database. If you're happy with that as a storage mechanism, then go for it. Just make sure you don't accidentally upload them to Github, etc.

Comment: Note, if the files are already outside the document root, then putting a .htaccess file there will have no additional affect.

Comment: @x43 , I don't know how to use SQL properly yet and XML seemed simpler to get started. Is there any big benefit to storing the login details in a database with SQL?

Comment: @ThW , I thought encrypt and hash was the same thing. Just read that encrypt is 2-way and hash is 1-way. Anyway I am using hash: ```` $hash = password_hash("12345", PASSWORD_BCRYPT); ````

Comment: @TimB XML *does* work, but it isn't a great practice.

Comment: A database usually is significiently faster than using a file based storage. And much less error prone.

Comment: @arkascha , why is a db faster, and why should XML be error prone?

Comment: @TimB A database approach _typically_ is much more effective for two reasons: 1. it is not the whjole file structure that has to e parsed and recreated for each modification and 2. there are far less file system operations involved which are the actual time consuming step, since the process has to wit for slower external operations (hardware and the like). This is based on the fact that database services do _not_ write every operation onto disk for obvious reasons. That is true for real databases services like MySQL, Oracle, PostGreSQL, not for SQLite and BerkelyDB.

Comment: @TimB The robustness of a file based approach fully depends on the consuming process itself: you have to implement all the logic yourself which means that you can make all mistakes everyone else already did before you. Using a database service on the other hand you benefit from the stable service which just works. And which assists you with helpful error messages, analyses and explanations in case there is an issue.